# How can a remote Git repository be configured for pushing to, no fetching or pulling?

Tags: git, git-branch

How can a remote Git repository be configured for pushing to, no fetching or pulling?

I have a repository in a location where it is not connected to a project management system, and I want to link it to another location where the project manager (Gogs) is.

How can I configure the local working copy to only push to the Gogs location, but never to pull from it, i.e. to ensure that a `git fetch` or `git pull` never references it?

How the `.git/config` entry for such a remote look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a fake fetch URL:

```
$ git remote set-url origin "https://{pulling-is-disabled-for-this-remote}"
$ # Below command is needed since git remote set-url sets both fetch and push URLs
$ git remote set-url --push origin CORRECT_REMOTE_URL
$ git pull origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://{pulling-is-disabled-for-this-remote}/': Could not resolve host: {pulling-is-disabled-for-this-remote}
```

Thus, the `.git/config` entry for such a remote will look like below:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://{pulling-is-disabled-for-this-remote}
    pushurl = CORRECT-URL-MUST-BE-PUT-HERE
```

---

The following bash function will do the job:

```
git_disable_pull_from_remote()
{
    if [ $# -ne 1 ];
    then
        echo 1>&2 "Usage: git_disable_pull_from_remote <remote_repo>"
        return 1
    fi

    local url="$(git remote get-url --push "$1")"
    git remote set-url "$1" "https://{pulling-is-disabled-for-this-remote}"
    git remote set-url --push "$1" "$url"
}
```

Example:

```
$ git_disable_pull_from_remote origin
```

Comment: should creating the remote directly in `.git/config' with only `pushurl` without adding `url`, ie  without using the `git remote` commands accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Would creating an entry directly in '.git/config' with only `pushurl` without adding `url` and `fetch` suffice, ie without using `git remote`, or would that risk some errors during the push? Does the `fetch` setting have some effect on `pushurl` only remote?

Comment: @vfclists What's the problem with using `git remote` for the task?

Comment: because I am not sure where the `git remote` command has other effects besides adding the minimum changes I expect in `.git/config`

Comment: I don't think that `git remote` has other side-effects, but if you are concerned, then I believe that adding the entry in `.git/config` directly (though including both `url` and `pushurl`) should work fine.

Comment: The problem is I want to compare the state of the pushonly repo with `git remote show pushonly` repo, but the command fails because the answer fakes the `url`? So how do I get `git remote show pushonly` to work when its `url` has been faked to prevent pulling from it?

Comment: You will have to temporarily enable pulling from `pushonly` before calling `git remote show` on it. You can create a special script for that.